# Strip parts of string in excel

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have a a column in excel with the follow example bellow in each cell:

"On Leave: 14-08-2011

On Leave: 16-03-2012

Return From Leave: 01-01-2013

Return From Leave: 09-03-2012"

Sometimes I have more or less information. I just need to find one way (formula or vba) to find the last "On Leave:" string and copy date to another column.

In this case the result would be "16-03-2012"

The goal here is to find the greatest date on leave.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  Are the strings in one cell or in two cells? (Date in its own cell?)

Comment: Hi Ron, here you can see the excel example http://i.stack.imgur.com/y3ePE.jpg  you can see in the column A the problem and in the column B the desired result.

I need always the date of the last "On Leave".

Comment: I would suggest a VBA solution, given the complexity of your data. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to have another column could you not just do something like this if I assume your text string is in column A:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,8)="On Leave",DATEVALUE(MID(A1,11,10)),1)
```

Then just find the max of that.

Answer (score 0):

just using data in a1:a9 I used the following array formula to give the last row number

```
=MAX(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("on leave",$A$1:$A$9))),ROW($A$1:$A$9)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one (assuming the pattern doesn't vary)

```
=MAX(IF(LEFT($A$2:$A$10,8)="on leave",DATEVALUE(RIGHT($A$2:$A$10,10))))
```

entered as an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"On Leave","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"On Leave","")))/LEN("On Leave")))+LEN("On Leave : "),10)
```

If you want to first check for the string "On Leave" in cell use:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,8)="On Leave",MID(A1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"On Leave","@",(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"On Leave","")))/LEN("On Leave")))+LEN("On Leave : "),10),"")
```

[image]